# How Do I Quickly Reflector, Then Up Smash?

Tags: super-smash-bros-melee

In [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pD_imYhNoQ4) (language NSFW), at 0:15, the Fox labeled "Tang" performs what appears to be a reflector followed by an up smash. The reflector animation only plays for about a frame, before the up smash comes out.

When I attempt to perform these moves in sequence, with down+b followed by up+a, the full animation of the reflector plays, and my opponent has been knocked out of range by the time the up smash occurs.

How can I quickly reflector and up smash, the way Tang does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't actually find a reference for this particular combo, but I am pretty sure that in that video Tang is pressing up+a within a frame or two of pressing down+b. This cancels the rest of the animation for Fox's reflector and goes right into the next attack. In other words, I think you just have to be really fast.

This combo is similar to the more commonly used [waveshine](http://super-smash-bros.wikia.com/wiki/Waveshine), which also involves transitioning from Fox's reflector into another move before the reflector animation finishes.

Comment: Looks like there really is nothing to it other than doing down + b and up + a very fast. The technical explanation is: a reflector can be cancelled by a jump, and a jump can be cancelled by an up smash. So the "up" part of the up + a cancels the reflector, and the "a" makes you smash instead of jump. One important thing to note is, the combo won't work if you try to smash using the c-stick.

Answer (score 2):

What happened there is, a shine then a jump-cancelled up smash.

What is jump-cancelling?:
When you press jump, the are a few frames of delay before you jump (about 3 - 8 depending on the character), within these frames of crouching down before you jump you can execute up smash, up B, grab, or the item throw, and since shine can be cancelled by jumping it works and must be done very fast.

The exact inputs are:

- Shine-----------------------------(down + b)
- Shine-cancel--------------------(X or Y)
- Jump-cancelled Up smash---(Up smash very shortly after previous input)